# Backup project on regular basis?

Tags: android-studio, project

Thanks to SO and contributors for so much, I've been successful in learning how to make basic apps work. Maybe I can contribute with this: I've been backing up the entire project directory each day. For example in Windows I copy:

C:\MyApp to C:\Bkups\022622

As the Android Studio project size keeps mounting I could run out of space for the backups.

I have tried deleting the Intermediates directory and that halves the project size.

I have tried gradlew clean build at the terminal: it doubled the project size.

Note too I have used :

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
```

in the build.gradle file

and I have used the Refractor to remove unused resources. The projects just keep getting bigger.

I would like a fast clean backup method. It looks like my option is to backup only:

C:\MyApp\app\src to C:\Bkups\022622

and then restore that directory if/when I have to.

Comment: Is source control not an option, such as using git? That doesnt eliminate full backups, but only keeps track of source code and other source files, so you can build the project at any point in time.

Comment: @Caramiriel Thanks for your comment! Though not a team, this looks worth a try to see the ease and speed in backing up the source files. GitHub has been around a really long time, and so, respectable. And I want to learn more about this...because backups are everything.